# Uproot and Dask

Tags: python, dask, uproot

I am experimenting with the dask functionality of uproot, i.e. loading branches into dask arrays.

Unfortunately I am not understanding why things happen when trying to perform computations on these arrays, e.g.

```
import dask.array as da

tree = uproot.dask("file.root:tree", library = 'np')
branch_data = data["testbranch"]
mean = da.mean(branch_data).compute()
```

The branch data is a 2-dimensional array and I would like to compute the mean along `axis=1`, i.e. for each row. Strangely the output is the same as if i did:

```
np.mean(branch_data.T, axis = 1)
```

It somehow computes the mean of the columns instead. Trying to add `axis=1`results in an error saying axis out of bounds for array with dimension 1. But calling `compute()` on the branch to print the actual data it clearly is the expected 2-dim array. This also happens with other methods like da.sum().

**EDIT:** Here I provide an example that reproduces the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import uproot

# creating sample file with tree
with uproot.recreate("test.root") as file:
    file["test_tree"] = {"test_branch": np.random.random((100,10))}

# Standard uproot (output I aim for with the dask option)
tree = uproot.open("./test.root:test_tree")
branch = tree["test_branch"].array(library = 'np')
mean = np.mean(branch, axis = 1)
print(mean)

# Uproot-Dask (Will compute mean columnwise but would expect a single scalar. Strange...)
tree = uproot.dask("./test.root:test_tree", library = 'np')
branch = tree["test_branch"]
mean = np.mean(branch).compute()
print(mean)

#This should correspond to the standard uproot ouput but does not work. Also strange
mean = np.mean(branch, axis = 1).compute()
print(mean)
```

Comment: Please provide a value for `data` so we can reproduce this. Your real data is probably big, but try to make as small an example as you can that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Hey I added an example which reproduces the problem. At least on my machine.

Comment: Much better, thanks. I added the imports so the code can be cut and pasted. I can reproduce this now, after installing `dask` and `uproot`. The Dask version is odd because what you get has shape `(100,)` instead of `(100,10)` and the rows don't have a length. I don't understand the object `uproot.dask()` is creating for you, hopefully someone here who knows that library can help you.

Comment: Ah, got it: https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot._dask.dask.html says that "uproot.dask (this function): returns an unevaluated Dask array from TTrees.". If you evaluate it using `branch.compute()`, then you'll get a (100,10) Numpy array.

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper response, but the key thing that's missing from this discussion is that `uproot.dask` doesn't return a `dask.array`, which is a lazy rectangular array, it returns a `dask_awkward.Array`, which is a lazy ragged array, without a consistent `shape` (in general; depends on the ROOT file).

Comment: Or more accurately, if your data supports it, passing `library="np"` to `uproot.dask` would give you a `dask.array` (or an error of the data in the file is ragged). The default `library="ak"` argument gives you a `dask_awkward.Array`, for which `dask_awkward.sum` is the function that does summation of ragged arrays lazily (similar to how `awkward.sum` does summation of ragged arrays eagerly).

Comment: Ok that is good to know! Nevertheless I do not see how this explains the seemingly strange output I get.

Comment: @JimPivarski Hi Jim, you would really help me if you could explain. I understand what is being returned depending on the library argument provided but the reason for the output I get is still not clear to me. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't seen the output. I tried to make some examples to see if `branch` (as defined above; it's just a `dask.array`) would return an array for `branch.mean().compute()`, but no: it returns a scalar as I expect. What is the data type of the data in the file? It has to be a fixed-size array per entry (and hence, the array for all entries is 2-dimensional) for `axis=1` to be meaningful.

Comment: I am confused. When you look at my concrete example, I get an array of 10 entries when calling ```np.mean(branch).compute()```, I double checked it now. But I totally agree that I also would expect a scalar! That is the first strange output.
The value of ```branch``` is a ```dask.array``` with ```shape(100,)```.
The second strange thing: Ultimately my aim is to get the same output as in the standard uproot block of my code. But ```np.mean(branch, axis = 1).compute()``` does not work at all and gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the uproot manual, the [`uproot.dask()`](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot._dask.dask.html) function "returns an unevaluated Dask array from `TTrees`."

Playing with the `branch` object you created in your sample code, I was able to convert it to a plain Numpy array by calling `compute()` on it:

```
import numpy as np
import uproot

with uproot.recreate("test.root") as file:
    file["test_tree"] = {"test_branch": np.random.random((100,10))}

tree = uproot.dask("./test.root:test_tree", library = 'np')
branch = tree["test_branch"]
b_as_array = branch.compute()
```

Continuing interactively:

```
>>> branch
dask.array<test_branch-from-uproot, shape=(100,), dtype=float64, chunksize=(100,), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
>>> b_as_array = branch.compute()
>>> b_as_array.shape
(100, 10)
>>> np.mean(b_as_array, axis=0)
array([0.54450986, 0.48361194, 0.52477069, 0.50902231, 0.52925032,
       0.47309532, 0.49022969, 0.48736406, 0.5027256 , 0.56298907])
```

Note that I had to use `axis=0` to get the mean you want since `np.mean(b_as_array)` returned just one number being the average of all 1000 numbers.

Now, you probably want to keep the efficiency of Dask arrays, and Dask itself provides the same operations. You should probably use the Dask implementations rather than the equivalent Numpy ones.

E.g.

```
>>> branch.mean().compute()
array([0.54450986, 0.48361194, 0.52477069, 0.50902231, 0.52925032,
       0.47309532, 0.49022969, 0.48736406, 0.5027256 , 0.56298907])
```

Lots more details at https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array.html

Comment: I admit this is not a fully satisfactory answer because things like `branch.mean(axis=1)` still don't work. I'm not sure how to fully manipulate `branch` as a Dask array without casting it back to a regular array.

Comment: ```branch.mean().compute()``` gives the same as ```np.mean(branch.T, axis = 1)```, which I find Strange. I do not see any possibility of getting the equivalent of ```np.mean(branch, axis =1)``` (that is what I want) with the dask implementation of mean.

Comment: Yeah, what I gathered is that Dask is meant to give you lazy implementations on large datasets that are not loaded until they're actually needed, and they didn't implement all the operations, only those that made sense for the optimizations needed for the use cases they have in mind.

Comment: My take here would be to read through https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/10-minutes-to-dask.html carefully and try to understand the whole Dask computing model, and then what you're seeing here might start making sense.